# C# Inheritance. Could someone check if I did this right?

Tags: c#, inheritance, uml, instance, protected

[image: INSTRUCTION]

This is what I've come up from the instruction. And I'm still not sure if I did it right. The instruction doesn't require any output and didn't gave examples.So I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Hope someone could help. Thank you!

````
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{

    public class User
    {
        private string user_id;
        protected string user_password;

        public User(string id, string pass)
        {
            this.user_id = id;
            this.user_password = pass;
        }
        public bool verifyLogin(string id, string pass)
        {
            return Equals(this.user_id, this.user_password);
        }
        public void updatePassword(string newPassword)
        {
            this.user_password = newPassword;
        }
    }

    public class Administrator : User
    {
        private string admin_name;

        public Administrator(string name, string id, string pass) : base(id, pass)
        {
            this.admin_name = name;
        }
        public void upatePassword(string newPassword)
        {
            base.updatePassword(newPassword);
        }
        public void updateName(string name)
        {
            this.admin_name = name;
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: I just followed the UML tho.

Comment: It says they should be part of the namespace `UserNamespace` but the namespace they're in is called `CSharp_Shell`

Answer (score 3):

`updatePassword` in the base class should be `abstract` as it is said by the subject.

It means `User` class should be abstract as well and derived class will override `updatePassword` method.

Comment: Now I made ```User``` and abstract
then under ```User``` class is ```public abstract void updatePassword(string newPassword);``` Then under ```Administrator``` is ```public override void updatePassword(string newPassword)
        {
            this.user_password = newPassword;
        }```

Comment: @JoshuaUngson yes, looks fine.

Comment: @JohnG No, you are not missing anything. The `User` type cannot be instantiated (no `User` object can be declared). If whoever made that task wanted `User` instances, should have chosen `virtual` instead `abstract` in the `User.updatePassword` method

Comment: @JohnG depends on "is it really necessary to create `User` objects".  `User` is also italic  on the diagram